# Audioplayer not sync with Fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, audio-player

I am trying to create a music player in `ViewPager` when the user swipes, the player should play the next song. The views are updating correctly but the song is not sync with them. For example, it's playing the second song in the first fragment. I tried a lot of things but I'm not able to find where is the issue. Please anyone give me a solution. Thanks in advance.

```
public class AudioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<PlayerModel> audioList;
    int position;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio);
        audioList=getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(getString(R.string.SONG_LIST));
        position=getIntent().getIntExtra(getString(R.string.SONG_POSITION),0);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
    }


    AudioActivity.ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapter = new AudioActivity.ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        AudioPlayerAdapter audioPlayerAdapter=new AudioPlayerAdapter();
        for(int i=0;i<audioList.size();i++) {
            adapter.addFragment(audioPlayerAdapter.newInstance(audioList, i), AppConstants.AUDIO_PLAYER);
        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new CubeInTransformer());



    }



    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }


        public void setFragment(Fragment fragment, int position,String title) {
            mFragmentList.set(position,fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.set(position,title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

My Fragment

```
public class AudioPlayerAdapter extends Fragment implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    Button btnStart, btnStop, btnBind, btnUnbind, btnUpby1, btnUpby10;
    TextView textStatus, textIntValue, textStrValue;
    Messenger mService = null;
    boolean mIsBound;
    public static Handler messageHandler;
    long duration, currSongPosition;


    ImageView displayArt;
    TextView playerName;
    TextView totTime;
    TextView fromTime;
    List<PlayerModel> songList;
    RecyclerView songRecyclerView;
    ImageButton showList;
    ImageButton playAudio;
    ImageButton pauseAudio;
    ImageButton stepForward;
    ImageButton stepBackward;
    ImageButton shuffleAudio;
    ImageButton volumeAudio;
    ImageButton repeatAudio;
    int songPosition;
    SeekBar songProgressBar;
    SeekBar volumeSeekBar;
    private Intent playIntent;
    //binding
    private boolean musicBound = false;
    private float x1, x2;
    static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 150;


    //activity and playback pause flags
    private boolean paused = false, playbackPaused = false;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
    private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
    private int currentSongIndex = 0;
    private boolean isShuffle = false;
    private boolean isRepeat = false;


    public AudioPlayerAdapter newInstance(List<PlayerModel> playerList, int position) {

        AudioPlayerAdapter fragment = new AudioPlayerAdapter();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putParcelableArrayList(AppConstants.SONG_LIST, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) playerList);
        b.putInt(AppConstants.SONG_POSITION, position);

        fragment.setArguments(b);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_music_player, container, false);

        songList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(getString(R.string.SONG_LIST));
        songPosition = getArguments().getInt(getString(R.string.SONG_POSITION), 0);

        LogUtil.error("Song Position",songPosition+"-->"+songList.get(songPosition).getPlayerTitle());

        FieldIntialization(view);
        if (playIntent == null) {
            playIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MusicService.class);
            playIntent.setAction(String.valueOf(MusicService.MSG_FOREGROUND));
            playIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(getString(R.string.SONG_LIST), (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) songList);
            playIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.SONG_POSITION), songPosition);
            getActivity().startService(playIntent);
        }
        DataInitialization(songPosition);


        messageHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case MusicService.MSG_SET_INT_VALUE:
                        break;
                    case MusicService.MSG_PLAY:
                        LogUtil.error("Pause", "Pause");
                        playAudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_24dp);
                        break;
                    case MusicService.MSG_PAUSE:
                        LogUtil.error("Play", "Play");
                        playAudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_white_24dp);
                        break;
                    case MusicService.MSG_NEXT:
                        songPosition = msg.getData().getInt(getString(R.string.SONG_POSITION));
                        LogUtil.error("SonPos", String.valueOf(songPosition));
                        updatePlayerView(songPosition);
                        break;
                    case MusicService.MSG_PREVIOUS:
                        songPosition = msg.getData().getInt(getString(R.string.SONG_POSITION));
                        LogUtil.error("SonPos", String.valueOf(songPosition));
                        updatePlayerView(songPosition);
                        break;
                    case MusicService.MSG_UPDATE_SEEKBAR:
                        duration = msg.getData().getLong(getString(R.string.SONG_DURATION));
                        currSongPosition = msg.getData().getLong(getString(R.string.SONG_CURR_DURATION));
                        break;
                    case MusicService.MSG_SHUFFLE_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Shuffle Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case MusicService.MSG_SHUFFLE_ON:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Shuffle On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case MusicService.MSG_REPEAT_ON:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Repeat On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case MusicService.MSG_REPEAT_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Repeat Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case MusicService.MSG_CLOSE:
                        getActivity().finish();
                        break;
                    case MusicService.MSG_STOP:
                        break;
                    default:
                        super.handleMessage(msg);
                }
            }
        };

        return view;
    }

  /*  @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
      *//*  outState.putString("textStatus", textStatus.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("textIntValue", textIntValue.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("textStrValue", textStrValue.getText().toString());*//*
    }

    private void restoreMe(Bundle state) {
        if (state != null) {*//*
            textStatus.setText(state.getString("textStatus"));
            textIntValue.setText(state.getString("textIntValue"));
            textStrValue.setText(state.getString("textStrValue"));*//*
        }
    }*/

    public void stopService() {
        getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity(), MusicService.class));
    }


    private void sendMessageToService(int action) {

        Intent startIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MusicService.class);
        startIntent.setAction(String.valueOf(action));
        getActivity().startService(startIntent);


    }

    private void sendMessageToServiceWithData(int action, int currPosition) {

        Intent startIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MusicService.class);
        startIntent.setAction(String.valueOf(action));
        startIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.SEEK_POSITION), currPosition);

        getActivity().startService(startIntent);


    }


    private void FieldIntialization(View view) {
        songProgressBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        volumeSeekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.volumeSeekBar);
        displayArt = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.songImage);
        playerName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.songName);
        totTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.endTime);
        fromTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.startTime);
        songRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.songRecyclerView);
        showList = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.showList);
        stepForward = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.step_next);
        stepBackward = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.step_prev);
        shuffleAudio = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.shuffle);
        repeatAudio = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.repeat);
        playAudio = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.play_pause);
        volumeAudio = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.speaker);
        playAudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_24dp);
        songRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MarginDecoration(getActivity()));
        songRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        songRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        SongRecyclerAdapter songRecyclerAdapter = new SongRecyclerAdapter(songList,
                getActivity()
        );
        if (songList.size() > 0) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp =
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            songRecyclerView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        } else {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp =
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            songRecyclerView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
        songRecyclerView.setAdapter(songRecyclerAdapter);

        songRecyclerAdapter.setOnDataChangeListener(new onRefreshFavListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFavRefresh(int position) {
                playIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MusicService.class);
                playIntent.setAction(String.valueOf(MusicService.MSG_FOREGROUND));
                playIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(getString(R.string.SONG_LIST), (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) songList);
                playIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.SONG_POSITION), position);
                getActivity().startService(playIntent);
                updatePlayerView(position);
            }
        });

    }


    private void DataInitialization(final int position) {
        showList.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_up_white_24dp);
        showList.setTag(R.drawable.ic_up_white_24dp);
        songRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        LogUtil.error("Update",position+"-->"+songList.get(position));
        updatePlayerView(position);

        showList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ((int) showList.getTag() == R.drawable.ic_up_white_24dp) {
                    showList.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_down_white_24dp);
                    showList.setTag(R.drawable.ic_down_white_24dp);
                    songRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    showList.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_up_white_24dp);
                    showList.setTag(R.drawable.ic_up_white_24dp);
                    songRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        volumeSeekBar.setMax(audioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        volumeSeekBar.setProgress(audioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));


        volumeSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        progress, 0);
            }
        });


        playAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                sendMessageToService(MusicService.MSG_CHECK_PLAYING_STATUS);

            }
        });

        stepForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                sendMessageToService(MusicService.MSG_NEXT);
            }
        });

        stepBackward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                sendMessageToService(MusicService.MSG_PREVIOUS);
            }
        });

        shuffleAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendMessageToService(MusicService.MSG_SHUFFLE);
            }
        });

        repeatAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendMessageToService(MusicService.MSG_REPEAT);
            }
        });

    }


    public void updatePlayerView(int songIndex) {
        playAudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_24dp);
        LogUtil.error("Song List",songIndex+"-->"+songList.get(songIndex).getPlayerTitle());

        playerName.setText(songList.get(songIndex).getPlayerTitle());
        totTime.setText(Utility.convertDuration(Long.parseLong(songList.get(songIndex).getPlayerDuration())));

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(songList.get(songIndex).getPlayerAlbumId())},
                null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        displayArt.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        displayArt.setImageBitmap(Constants.getDefaultAlbumArt(getActivity(), songList.get(songIndex).getPlayerAlbumId()));
        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setMax(100);

        // Updating progress bar
        updateProgressBar();

    }

    public void updateProgressBar() {
//        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    }

    /**
     * Background Runnable thread
     */
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            sendMessageToService(MusicService.MSG_UPDATE_SEEKBAR);
            // Displaying Total Duration time
            totTime.setText("" + Utility.milliSecondsToTimer(duration));
            // Displaying time completed playing
            fromTime.setText("" + Utility.milliSecondsToTimer(currSongPosition));

            // Updating progress bar
            int progress = (int) (Utility.getProgressPercentage(currSongPosition, duration));
            //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
            songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);


            // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

    }

    /**
     * When user starts moving the progress handler
     */
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
//        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    }

    /**
     * When user stops moving the progress hanlder
     */
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
//        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        int currentPosition = Utility.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), (int) duration);

        sendMessageToServiceWithData(MusicService.MSG_SEEK, currentPosition);

        // update timer progress again
        updateProgressBar();
    }

}
```